# Get index of parent LI and assign as <A> href with jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs, indexing, parent

I am trying to get the index of the parent li and assign it as part of the href in my anchor tag. Right now, all I am getting is a href="#tab-1" for all of my anchors instead of #tab-1, #tab-2, etc.
here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.jqueryTabs ul li a').attr("href", "#tab" + $(this).parent().index());
});
</script>
<div class="jqueryTabs">

 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div id="">
 </div>
 <div id="">
 </div>
 <div id="">
 </div>
 <div id="">
 </div>
 <div id="">
 </div>

</div><!-- jqueryTabs -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each selected `a`, and get the value of each individual `a`'s parent, otherwise the all get the same value.

Try this instead:

```
$(function(){
    $('.jqueryTabs ul li a').each(function(i, elm) {
       $(this).attr("href", "#tab" + $(this).parent().index());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$(function(){
     $('.jqueryTabs ul li a').each(function(){
         $(this).attr("href", "#tab" + $(this).parent().index());
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through the anchors and for each of them get the index of the parent LI:

```
$(function(){
    $('.jqueryTabs ul li a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("href", "#tab" + ($(this).parent().index() + 1));
    });
});
```

**Note**: I have added the **"+ 1"** to get "tab1", "tab2"... index() is zero-based

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/H8aCK/)**